# Compute from 2 pivot tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to compute and display on graph employee turnover dynamically (#terminations/#headcount) i.e. only loading data into the tables and being able to explore the data (by division/by date/quarter/year).
Data comes from 2 tables:
Organisation headcount (list of headcount by date by division)
Terminations (list of individual termination, by date and type, voluntary or not).

I have 1 pivot to compute average headcount by month/quarter/year and another one to summarise terminations by type and by date.

How would you go about it? If possible without a macro.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen an Excel 2016 demo that shows using multiple data tables for a pivot table. I don't think earlier versions can do this; I got the impression it was new for '16.

It can be done in earlier versions, but you'd have to combine the data into one table. Bigger brains than me may have a better solution for pre '16.

Good luck!